# SAS macro do-loop with data step

Tags: sas

This is my first macro, so my apologies if I missed something simple.

I need to do the same data step six (or more) times and append each one to the first, so I tried a do-loop within a macro. Everything works with the loop removed, but once the do-loop is added, I get errors that either say I have an extra %end or an extraneous %mend.  All ideas welcome. Thanks!

```
%macro freeze_samples(orig_file=, samples= , Start_Freeze_Incr=, 
           End_Freeze_Incr= );
%do i = 1 %to &samples;

data freeze_slice_&i;  
    set &orig_file;

     (do stuff)

run;

    * If we have more than one slice, append to previous slice(s).;
    %if &i > 1 %then %do;
        proc append base = temp_1 data = temp_&i;
        run;
    %end;

%end;

%mend;
```

Comment: This is a non-issue that can be resolved by restarting the SAS session.

Answer (score 4):

I think you either have a problem you didn't include in the text (ie, in the 'do stuff' section) or you have a bad session (ie, you fixed the problem but there's something from a previous run messing up something now).  This runs fine (given I don't know what you're doing):

```
%macro freeze_samples(orig_file=, samples= , Start_Freeze_Incr=, 
           End_Freeze_Incr= );
%do i = 1 %to &samples;

data freeze_slice_&i;  
    set &orig_file;

     *(do stuff);

run;

    * If we have more than one slice, append to previous slice(s).;
    %if &i > 1 %then %do;
        proc append base = freeze_slice_1 data = freeze_slice_&i;  
        run;
    %end;

%end;

%mend;

%freeze_samples(orig_file=sashelp.class,samples=2,start_freeze_incr=1,end_freeze_incr=5);
```

I would note that you're probably better off not doing whatever you're doing this way; in SAS, there is usually a better way than splitting data off into multiple datasets.  But since I don't know what you're doing I can't really suggest the better way beyond recommending reading [this article](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf) and keeping it in mind (even if you're doing something different than bootstrapping, the concept applies to almost everything in SAS).

Comment: Thanks for the your help. In all the Googling I did, I never found that particular article. The missing code samples from the current data by choosing a random date within a range and then recording which of the study samples freeze within a date range AFTER the randomly chosen date.

Comment: Joe, you were right- the code worked once I restarted SAS. *face palm*